# Can xcodebuild automatically install and launch the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcodebuild

I am working on an ANT build that will build a project for use within the iOS simulator. Is it possible to have xcodebuild automatically launch the simulator and install the compiled app (similar to how Xcode does it)?

Answer (score 3):

Not with xcodebuild command, no.

I use the following to great effect: https://github.com/jhaynie/iphonesim

It has the option to launch an app directly in the simulator.